# ¿Como calcular la suma de varios totales?

Tags: javascript, scope, calculo

Tengo un array de objetos en los que estoy creando propiedades que necesito mostrar en el html. Esta es la estructura de uno de los objetos del array

```
{
    "functional_id": "201911291131250012400000SD4AYAA1",
    "transactions": [
      {
        "quantity": 2,
        "price": 140,
        "item": {
          "name": "Carton de 10 coffrets",
          "description": "+ 2 recharges d'argile offertes",
          "product": {
            "name": "Coffret empreinte rouge"
          }
        },
        "amount": 280
      },
      {
        "quantity": 2,
        "price": 17,
        "item": {
          "name": "1 lanterne d'accueil + 1 accroche porte",
          "product": {
            "name": "Lanterne d'accueil",
            "description": "Lors d'une euthanasie, cette affichette verticale auto-éclairée par bougie LED, est disposée à l’accueil. Elle montre l’importance de ce moment pour votre clinique. <br /> Les accroches porte déposés sur les poignées des salles de consultation invitent au calme."
          }
        },
        "amount": 34
      },
      {
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "item": {
          "name": "Petit modèle",
          "description": "Par 25",
          "product": {
            "name": "Sacs blancs",
            "description": "Pour les crémations Plurielles"
          }
        },
        "amount": 0
      },
      {
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "item": {
          "name": "Moyen modèle",
          "description": "Par 20",
          "product": {
            "name": "Sacs blancs",
            "description": "Pour les crémations Plurielles"
          }
        },
        "amount": 0
      },
      {
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "item": {
          "name": "Grand modèle",
          "description": "Par 10",
          "product": {
            "name": "Sacs blancs",
            "description": "Pour les crémations Plurielles"
          }
        },
        "amount": 0
      },
      {
        "quantity": 2,
        "price": 0,
        "item": {
          "product": {
            "name": "Carnet de conventions"
          }
        },
        "amount": 0
      }
    ],
    "date": "29/11/2019",
    "order_number": "113125"
  }
```

en este punto creo una propiedad "amount" para cada "transaction" para calcular la cantidad total de la compra de cada producto.

```
 public inicializeData() {

        this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(true);
        this.cartsSubscription = this.cartsService.getCarts().subscribe(carts => {
            this.orders = carts;
            this.orders.forEach(cart => {
                const day = cart.functional_id.substring(6, 8);
                const month = cart.functional_id.substring(4, 6);
                const year = cart.functional_id.substring(0, 4);
                cart.date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
                cart.order_number = cart.functional_id.substring(8, 14);
                cart.transactions.forEach(item => {
                    item.amount = item.quantity * item.price;
                });
            });
            this.load = true;
            this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(false);
        });
    }
```

El problema es que también necesitaría una cantidad total para todas las transacciones pero no puedo calcular este total. Primero he probado ha declarar una variable de clase con un valor de 0 y en el punto donde calculo el "item.amount" los sumo todos.

```
public amount = 0;

 public inicializeData() {

        this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(true);
        this.cartsSubscription = this.cartsService.getCarts().subscribe(carts => {
            this.orders = carts;
            this.orders.forEach(cart => {
                const day = cart.functional_id.substring(6, 8);
                const month = cart.functional_id.substring(4, 6);
                const year = cart.functional_id.substring(0, 4);
                cart.date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
                cart.order_number = cart.functional_id.substring(8, 14);
                cart.transactions.forEach(item => {
                    item.amount = item.quantity * item.price;
                    this.amount += item.amount;
                });
            });
            this.load = true;
            this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(false);
        });
    }
```

y veo que lo que obtengo es el total de todas las transacciones. Lo cual no lo que busco.

Entiendo que es un problema de scope. Pero también intenté declarar la variable dentro del forEach, pero tampoco funcionó.

```
 public inicializeData() {

        this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(true);
        this.cartsSubscription = this.cartsService.getCarts().subscribe(carts => {
            this.orders = carts;
            this.orders.forEach(cart => {
                const day = cart.functional_id.substring(6, 8);
                const month = cart.functional_id.substring(4, 6);
                const year = cart.functional_id.substring(0, 4);
                cart.date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
                cart.order_number = cart.functional_id.substring(8, 14);
                cart.transactions.forEach(item => {
                    item.amount = item.quantity * item.price;
                    let overallAmount = 0;
                    overallAmount += item.amount;
                });
            });
            this.load = true;
            this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(false);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.orders));
        });
    }
```

Lo que necesitaría es que en el objeto de ejemplo pudiera crear una propiedad que fuera la suma de todo el ítem.amount (en este caso sería overallAmount = 314).

Alguien que me haga ver mi error. Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Creo que solo te falta inicializar cada vez que se ejecute la función:

```
public amount = 0;

public inicializeData() {
    // Inicializas en cada ejecución
    this.amount = 0;
    this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(true);
    this.cartsSubscription = this.cartsService.getCarts().subscribe(carts => {
        this.orders = carts;
        this.orders.forEach(cart => {
            const day = cart.functional_id.substring(6, 8);
            const month = cart.functional_id.substring(4, 6);
            const year = cart.functional_id.substring(0, 4);
            cart.date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
            cart.order_number = cart.functional_id.substring(8, 14);
            cart.transactions.forEach(item => {
                item.amount = item.quantity * item.price;
                this.amount += item.amount;
            });
        });
        this.load = true;
        this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(false);
    });
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu idea, lo he probado y tampoco funciona. me sigue dando el valor total de la suma de todos los totales.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de nada dar las gracias todos los que habeis ayudado. He encontrado la solucion gracias a aproximaciones que me habeis dado. He terminado creando una propiedad en el objeto 'cart' en el que introduzco el valor de la suma del importe de cada uno de los articulos. 
Mi error principal se debia a que hacia todas la operaciones en el mismo scope o trataba de acumularlo en una variable de clase, la cual devolvia el total de todos los articulos.
Aqui os dejo mi solucion que funciona a la perfeccion.
De nuevo gracias por la ayuda

```
    public inicializeData() {

        this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(true);
        this.cartsSubscription = this.cartsService.getCarts().subscribe(carts => {
            this.orders = carts;
            this.orders.forEach(cart => {
                const day = cart.functional_id.substring(6, 8);
                const month = cart.functional_id.substring(4, 6);
                const year = cart.functional_id.substring(0, 4);
                cart.date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
                cart.order_number = cart.functional_id.substring(8, 14);
                const cash = [];
                cart.overallAmount = 0;
                cart.transactions.forEach(item => {
                    item.amount = item.quantity * item.price;
                    cash.push(item.amount);
                    cart.overallAmount = cash.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
                });
            });
            this.load = true;
            this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(false);
        });
    }
```